# How to clean cookie of target domain before redirect to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, cookies, session-cookies

I have two apps. First on
**mysite.test.com**

second on **mysite-api.test.com**
Last one is login page of IS4 to login. During login I set cookie like this

```
 httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("ClientId", new CookieOptions(){ Domain = ".mysite-api.test.com", Secure = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.None});
```

As result:
[image]

There is case when I redirect from **mysite.test.com** to **mysite-api.test.com**, but before it's necessary to clean cookie of last one.

I made endpoint on my backend [image]

Using JS I make a call to **mysite-api.test.com/api/cleanCookie** from domain **mysite.test.com** and get a response

[image]

But in the end it does not delete cookie. What I did wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of this cookie, exactly? Is it in any way related to OAuth2/OIDC's `client_id` claim? And if so, do you have a good reason for exposing it this way?

Comment: @Dai it's our internal cookie, it's not related to OAuth2/OIDC's, and it's not real name of cookie

Comment: @РомаМатковский, try to follow this link explanation [Microsoft - Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0)